# Numpy dot use all the memory

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm playing with 6 satellite images using Python3. I read the image to a `NumPy` array using [Rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio). The elemets of all this matrix are `numpy.uint8`, the shape are  `7041x8111` and the size of any matrix (B1 for example) is `B1.nbytes/1024/1024 = 54.4` MB.

My problem is, when I try to multiply 2 matrix by scalar and then add them, use 1GB of RAM (I see this with htop).

**Edit** (post the code):

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio 

#Read the images and transform to a NumPy array
with rasterio.open('Fotos/LE72290822013146CUB0/LE72290822013146CUB00_B1.TIF', 'r') as b1_raster:
    B1 = b1_raster.read()

with rasterio.open('Fotos/LE72290822013146CUB00/LE72290822013146CUB00_B2.TIF', 'r') as b2_raster:
    B2 = b2_raster.read()

out = 0.3037*B1 + 0.2793*B2
```

This problem I have loading 2 images.

Why? if the matrix are much more light. There is another efficient way to do this? I use Debian 8, Python 3 and I test the code in Ipython3 version: 2.3

Comment: You forgot to post your code.

Comment: If you're loading six images that's 324Megs of RAM - are you creating a copy after multiplying (i.e. another 324Megs), and then another copy for the summed arrays (i.e. another 324 megs)? And to answer your question about another way: process them one (or at least not six) at a time?

Comment: Do the pixels get converted to floating point in out when multiplying by a real number?

Comment: Yes. multiple the matrix to 0.3 change from uint8 to float64, and the new size of the matrix is 450MB. Thanks  @barny